# What is the difference between .quit and .QUIT in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I just want to know the difference between `.quit` and `.QUIT` in pygame. I've tested both but I continue to not understand how they work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QUIT` is the enumerator constant for an event type (see [`event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module). The quit event occurs when the pygame window is closed:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        # [...]
```

[`quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) is a function which uninitialize all pygame modules. This function should be called at the end of the applicaiition:

```py
# initialize all imported pygame modules
pygame.init()

# application loop
while True:
    # [...]

# uninitialize all pygame modules
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The .QUIT in pygame is used to check if you pressed the cross button on the window which is a pygame event. If you have to quit a window you should press the cross button most of the times.

[image]
Here is a example of an image for with the cross button on a window

So when you press the cross arrow button on the window it quits the window so when you press the cross button on a pygame window it is stored in a event named pygame.QUIT.

pygame.quit() uninstializez all of pygame's modules i am not sure but after you say nthe line pygame.quit() you wont be able to use most of or all pygame function